# Null pointer exception with static Map

Tags: java, exception, static, initialization

It's 5am and I'm a bit asleep, so that may be it (also I'm relatively new with Java). But I don't see why this code generates Null Exception with this code. The map should be initialized by then, shouldn't it?

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> CONDS_MAP = 
    Collections.unmodifiableMap
    (
        new HashMap<String, Integer>()
            {{ 
                put("null", 0);
                put("false", 0);
                put("true", 1);
                put("numElems.lt", 2);
                put("NELT", 2);
                put("numElems.gt", 3);
                put("NEGT", 3);
            }}
    );

private int getCodeInt(Object code)
{
    if (code.getClass() == String.class)
    {
        return CONDS_MAP.get((String)code); // Null Exception here
    }
    else
    // (... etc etc)
}
```

Thanks! and sorry it it is too trivial...

Comment: Unrelated, but try to avoid the double brace HashMap initializer, and `code.getClass() == String.class` should be `code instanceof String` (easier to read, faster to type, avoids possible NPE).

Comment: @Thilo - What's wrong with an instance initializer?

Comment: @Ted: It creates an (unnecessary) subclass of HashMap.

Comment: @Thilo: Thanks for you recommendation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely caused by trying to unbox the null returned from a non-existing key.

```
return CONDS_MAP.get((String)code);
```

is the same as

```
return CONDS_MAP.get(code).intValue();
```

That last `intValue` will fail if the Map returns null.

Comment: I could swear that I put the dot in that json... but nah, code was "numElemsgt". Thanks. Sleeping may help. And also I will check for null values.

Comment: Different strings should return the same int. (I'll update the example)

Comment: Sure, but you could still say `put(NUM_ELEMS_GT, 3);` instead of `put("numElems.gt", 3);`

Comment: I don't see it working for me: I am using for reading data from a JSON file, and converting some Strings from the file to integer codes that later on are going to be switch'd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has been initialized by then, the nullpointerexception is probably caused by a null key.

Comment: Does a null key cause a NullPointerException ?

Comment: @Thilo Yes according to the docs - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29